# Arabic translation in latin1_swedish_ci collation PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, web, phpmyadmin

I have migrated my database from one hosting to another. The version of PHP and PHPmyadmin are very similar between both of them.
Some of my records in the database are Arabic. the collation I'm using is latin1_swedish_ci. It would read the arabic input and convert it into some weird characters. However, it decoded fine in the front-end (showed Arabic properly)

However, since I migrated my database. The front-end shows those weird characters rather than decoding it. Also, it's not able to store my Arabic inputs.

[what it looks like in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCG7k.png)

[What it should look like on the site (used to look like this originally)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NT3bL.png)

[What it looks like after I imported the database into another hosting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXZy9.png)

I did look this up on the internet, and it said to change my charset to UTF8, I tried doing that. It is able to store in arabic, but it still cannot translate those characters of my previous records.

I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: what backend are you using? maybe you should consider changing the collation type of your backend. It should match with your database collation type.

Comment: How do I found out what's the collation of my backend in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Collation is charset. You already know how to change it in phpmyadmin. But what framework are you using for your web application? When I say backend I mean the backend of your web application. You will change it there